# Backbone Local Storage "undefined is not a function"

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, backbone-local-storage

I am using [`Backbone.LocalStorage`](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage): **http://jsfiddle.net/jiewmeng/grhz9/3/**

```
$(function() {
    console.log(Backbone.LocalStorage); // undefined!!
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Todo,
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos")
    });
});​
```

The 1st `console.log()` gives `undefined`. Then there an error at the `localStorage: ...` line

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Expected since `Backbone.LocalStorage` is `undefined` but why?

Comment: Have you added <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.localStorage.js"></script> after loading backbone.js

Comment: @josnidhin, yes I did as in the jsFiddle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `backbone.localStorage-min.js` you're loading:

> http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js

looks like it is out of date and it doesn't define `Backbone.LocalStorage` at all. The version of `backbone.localStorage-min.js` that you are using defines `window.Store` rather than `Backbone.LocalStorage`. If you switch to that (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/grhz9/5/):

```
var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,
    localStorage: new Store("todos")
});
```

then you can get past building your `Todos` collection. I don't know how well things will work when you actually try to use it though. "Sun Aug 14 2011 09:53:55 -0400" is pretty much forever-ago in internet time so that version is rather antique.

If you switch to the latest version from Github:

> https://raw.github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/master/backbone.localStorage-min.js

you'll see that there are a few differences in the JavaScript and everything will start working when you use `new Backbone.LocalStorage('todos')`:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/grhz9/4/

Comment: As of February 1, 2013, CloudFlare's cdnjs is still serving the very-out-of-date August 14, 2011 copy. I had the same problem, didn't think to check whether the cdnjs version was up to date.

Comment: @joemaller: I wonder if that's a version number issue. The [github](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) page says v1.0 and talks about `Backbone.LocalStorage`, perhaps the old `window.Store` version was also marked as v1.0.

Comment: I think so, there are a couple open issues on the [CDN's github page](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/search?q=backbone.localStorage), hopefully they'll get it all straightened out.

Comment: All fixed: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js

Comment: As of February 2, the CDN is up to date :) See @RyanKirkman's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct - 1.0 is out of date.

I've updated backbone.localstorage to the latest version:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js  (production)

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage.js  (dev)

Hope that helps!