# Cannot use Backbone.localStorage

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-local-storage

I'm getting this error with FF: TypeError: Backbone.localStorage is not a constructor

This is the code:

```
app.MyCollection= Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.TestModel,
  localStorage: new Backbone.localStorage("test-backbone")
});
```

Anyone has an idea why this doesn't work? Not even to add the storage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone Local Storage "undefined is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867467/backbone-local-storage-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn! It was just a stupid typo.

The line should be:
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("test-backbone")
with an uppercase "L".

Not it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're using the right syntax for the plugin because there are several Backbone Localstorage plugins with various initialisation methods.